# Need to install Windows over Ubuntu without booting from USB/CD

Tags: boot, windows

Sometime back I installed Ubuntu on my desktop, not knowing that I was creating problems for the future. Now I want to re-install windows completely instead of Ubuntu, but my computer is not booting from USB or a CD, and I can't use the windows installer since i do not have a partition that is required by the windows installer. What should I do?

Comment: The fact that your computer is not booting from USB or CD has nothing to do with Ubuntu, you just have to select the booting device from BIOS and make sure the USB and/or CD are bootable.
Also, if you didn't take precautions to save the windows partition where the installer is, then you will definitely need windows on a DVD or USB stick to install.
Are you trying to dual-boot or are you just installing Windows on top of Ubuntu

Comment: windows on top of ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

just dd copy the image to a ntfs partition :)

the scenario would be a thin client that has ubuntu installed, and doesn't have USB ports or a dvd drive. or someone that is too poor to buy dvds or a usb pen drive but needs windows right now. the problem faced is when you use winusb to copy the image to hard drive, when you boot into install it bitches about no cd/dvd or usb drive present, the problem is freshlight doesn't install hard disk drive drivers to the image.